# Options for Overnight Between Flights in NYC?

Tags: airports, sleeping

I could arrive in JFK one night, and catch a cheap flight to my smaller city the next morning. So, I'm thinking of over-nighting there.

What are my best options? Is sleeping in the airport feasible? What are the costs of hotels, are they attached to the airport / how much do they cost / how hard are they to get to / how much does it cost to get to them?

TO BE CLEAR:
In General, what are the rough price ranges of cheap options, including the feasibility of sleeping at the airport?

Side notes:
These flights have to be bought separately, non-negotiable--if I ever put my small city in as final destination, flights are always $400 more than if I buy them separately.

I'm also explicitly trying to catch this flight so I can fly on same flight with my brother, and there is no reasonable flight later that same night from the same airport to my small town.

Comment: NYC is notoriously expensive but prices vary drastically with supply and demand so you should check a few websites (booking.com,google. hipmunk.com) for your specific dates. For inside the airport check out https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/new-york-city-jfk-airport-guide.htm

Comment: Depending on your flight times (and on the weather!) you might be interested in having a nap at [Rockaway Beach](https://www.nycgovparks.org/parks/rockaway-beach-and-boardwalk/), which opens at 6 a.m.

Comment: The Hotel Association of New York City has 270 members and many of these will offer rooms at different price points (there are roughly 75000 rooms between these 270 members). Private rooms are listed on airbnb, craigslist and more (a fair amount of them are illegal but oh well). Picking one from the thousands of choices is not easy -- and changes from one night to the night. To and from JFK is a topic rehashed here and searchable on Google easily as well. So parts of this is trivial to answer, parts of it is impossible to.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I see you've edited your question, but it is still too broad and opinion-based to be answerable as asked. There is no "best" option for everyone. "Cheap" for a room in Manhattan might be $250, but that's still expensive compared to most places in most of the country. Some people might prefer to wander the streets of a city that never sleeps, as there are stores and restaurants open 24 hours. Some might ride the subway endlessly to and fro all night long. Some might get a room at the YMCA for under $100. Some might camp out at the train station. There's no one right answer.

Comment: Thanks @choster. Must every question have a single answer? I wanted a variety of options that qualify for the criteria asked, not the 'single best'. Already you mentioning the stores and restaurants open 24 hours makes me wonder about finding a 24 hour cafe or something (though I also would want information on difficulty and cost to get there and back, etc.). In other words, I'm saying the question is 'answerable' with a list of options, instead of a single choice. As for price, the list can just be sorted according to price--the choice of trade-off value can be left to the reader.

Comment: I'd like to mention in direct response to the listed reasons for putting on hold that (1) While I mention my itinerary to explain why I cannot work around my question, my exact itinerary isn't relevant--it's a general question, which is, "What are my cheapest options for dealing with an overnight layover in this city, especially if I'm willing to think outside of the box? (2) I'm not price-shopping a specific good (e.g., "find me the cheapest hotel during window x"), I'm asking for a list of generally cheap options to explore.